# howto add dropdown menu with multi dropdown bootstrap 3.1.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a multi format dropdown menu for http://wikisofts.com as follows:

Windows

```
- Business
   - Item 1
   - Item 2
   - Item 3
   ...
- Development Tools
   - Item 11
   - Item 12
   - Item 13
   ..
....
```

When auto expand menu with mouse move I'm using the bootstrap 3.x

thank you very much

Comment: what's the question?Let us see what you've tried so far

Comment: Thankf user3127896. I've done it before